# ¿De que manera se puede acceder al entity manager y security.password_encoder desde fuera de un bundle

Tags: symfony3, doctrine2, slim

Mi situación es la siguiente:
Estoy creando un servicio rest con Slim.Tengo mi servicio en una carpeta llamada Rest en el directorio /web.Desde ahi necesito acceder al entity manager para realizar consultas a la base de datos y ademas security.password_encoder porque necesito codificar un password que me llega por el rest y poder compararlo con uno que ya tengo en la base de datos que codifique de la misma manera. Hay alguna manera en que pudiera hacer esto?

Comment: he trabajado en symfony y estos servicios no recomiendaria que vayan en la carpera ./web, diria que van en su respectivo .src/Controllers, yo usaba fosrestbundle para implementar estos servicios rest (y la mayoria de empresas en las que he estado lo utilizan)

Comment: En adicción a eso debes ver toda la sección de security de symfony (en la versión que uses) [https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/security.html](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/security.html), ashi encontraras ejemplos que pueden servir para el tema de autenticación, autorización a esos servicios rest

Comment: lo coloque en la carpeta /web porque si los pongo dentro de un bundle no se que url deberia darle al usuario para que consuma el servicio,no se si me entiendes..algo como esto porque ahi en web seria wwww.proyecto/rest/servicio

Comment: pero si cualquier controlador de igual manera es publico para el usuario

Comment: que url se le daria al usuario externo que valla a consumir el servicio rest 

ubicado en esta ruta Proyecto\src\MiProyecto\MainBundle\rest   
siendo la direccion www.proyecto.cl